# Using "if all" in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Why this work

```
for td in alltd:
    if "style3" in td["class"] or "style4" in td["class"] or "style1" in td["class"]:
        td["class"] = "s1"
```

and this not?

```
for td in alltd:
    if all(x in td["class"] for x in ("style3", "style4", "style1")):
        td["class"] = "s1"
```

Comment: Because your use of `all()` is like putting an `and` between all the statements. Use `any()` to replicate the behavior of the above if-statement.

Comment: To use `all` you'd have to double negate the `any` expression and distribute a negation over the quantifier: `not all(x not in td["class"] for x in ...)`. In this case that would be silly, but if you see logical negation in your tests (e.g. `!=`), it might be simpler to switch forms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`all([x1,x2,...])` is basically the same as `x1 and x2 and ...`, not `x1 or x2 or ...`

```
>>> all([True, True])
True
>>> all([True, False])
False
```

Use `any()` instead.

```
>>> any([True,False])
True
```

Answer (score 6):

use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) if you're doing `or` based comaparison:

```
`if any(x in td["class"] for x in ("style3", "style4", "style1")):`
```

Help on **any(iterable)**:

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true.  # i.e `or` condition

Help on **all(iterable)**:

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true. # i.e `and` contition